# Route param as first element of the path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there any possibility to have a route parameter as first element of the path? 
For example, let's say we have portal with weather and city is our 'context' (there is no possibility to access any page without 'context'), so we want to have pages like:

```
/:city/dashboard
/:city/airhealth
```

How to add such paths in routes? I know there is possibility to have something like this:

```
/dashboard/:city
/airhealth/:city
```

but when all pages have to have city context first example is more suitable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there will be any problem in doing this. you just have to modify your routing file and your route link.

here is the code

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import ComponentOne from './component-one';
import ComponentTwo from './component-two';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'component-one', component: ComponentOne },
  { path: ':id/dashboard', component: ComponentTwo }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/component-one']">Component One</a>
      <a [routerLink]="[123,'dashboard']">Component Two (id: 123)</a>  <-- replace 123 with city name
    </nav>
    <div style="color: green; margin-top: 1rem;">Outlet:</div>
    <div style="border: 2px solid green; padding: 1rem;">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**component-two.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-two',
  template: 'Component Two with route param <b><code>ID: {{ id }}</code></b>'
})
export default class ComponentTwo {

  private id;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  private ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; // use (+) converts string 'id' to a number other wise use params['id'] directly
    });
  }

  private ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

here is the working plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Purfk2msPE1XcZgjowvd?p=preview